# Concurrent access to Java HashMap object

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I'm building a Java REST application where I'm using a HashMap to store some data.

As it has a server, it can handle multiple requests simultaneously that access the HashMap. All requests made check if the Map has a predefined value (that value depends on the request body) and if not, add that value to the Map and return it. In case the Map has that value already, it simply returns the value on the Map.

What should I take into consideration in order to have a working and reliable system? I will have many reads on the Map and some writes (mainly when the application starts as the Map will be empty).

**tl;dr**

- Java Server which will handle multiple and simultaneous requests.
- Every request will make at least a `Map.containsKey(someKey)` and eventually a `Map.get(someKey)`
- Some requests will make a `Map.put(someKey, someValue)`

Shall I use some kind of concurrent data structure?

*For the sake of argument, I know that using an in-memory solution is not reliable. This is not intended for production use, it is merely academical.*

Comment: "What should I take into consideration in order to have a working and reliable system" from a reliability perspective, any kind of in-memory storage is a poor choice.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html But the map may change from the point it reads "containsKey", to the point where a "get" is made. In that case locking may be the solution, but that will impact performance.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I know that, but I am not allowed to use a DB or something like that. This isn't for production use anyway, it is just a kind of academical exercise ;)

Comment: I think you need to specify your requirements in detail. If you simply require a thread-safe solution (race-conditions/thread visibility), then `ConcurrentHashMap` should work. But if it is important that the first request is also the final value throughout the lifetime of the map, then it might not be enough (if values differ), as two threads can end up getting false from `containsKey`, and then both call `put`. In that case you need `containsKey` and `put` to be an atomic operation.

Comment: @Jeppe: That atomic operation is provided by `ConcurrentMap#computeIfAbsent`

Comment: @Thilo wouldn't `ConcurrentMap#putIfAbsent` be a better option then? That way I wouldn't need to write the code to insert in the map as the method itself would do it

Comment: @LuisF: `computeIfAbsent` will also insert the result into the map. The difference is that `putIfAbsent` requires you to run the calculation for the value on every call to `putIfAbsent`, whereas `computeIfAbsent` will only compute it the first time around.

Comment: @Thilo Like the solution I have made in LuidF's other thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54280841/3717691 I can't decide if it's a good or bad decision, since the bucket(s) may block during this "expensive" computation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by assuming we are using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), a version of `HashMap` that has more predictable and intuitive memory consistency effects when accessed in parallel.

Given that, the largest consideration would be making all operations on a single key atomic if possible, or at least uninterruptible by another thread that wants to perform other operations on that key. If you're using Java 8 or later, using `ConcurrentHashMap`'s implementation of the [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method will keep other threads out while the new value is being computed and stored.

...Which is exactly what you want, as an application developer: to use a library that has been written, vetted, tested, and used by experts in the concurrency effects of the language and environment in which you are writing your application.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to keep it in memory, you need to use a ConcurrentHashMap.

But what happens if you restart the application and lose the memory data?

Comment: it is an kind of an academical exercise, I know that the best approach would be to persist it in a DB for example

Comment: Understood. Than use the ConcurrentHashMap.