# Java REST optimize data structure access

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Java REST application where one endpoint always deals with a `ConcurrentMap`. I am doing load tests and it is really bad when the load test starts to increase.

What strategies can I implement in order to improve the efficiency of the application?

Should I play around with Jetty threads, as it is the server I'm using? Or is it mainly code? Or both?

The method that becomes the bottleneck is the one below.

Basically I need to read some line from a given file. I can't store it on a DB, so I came up with this processing with a Map. However, I'm aware that for large files it will take long not only to get to the line and I risk the fact that the Map will consume much memory when it has many entries...

`dict` is the `ConcurrentMap`.

```
public String getLine(int lineNr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (lineNr > nrLines) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (dict.containsKey(lineNr)) {
        return dict.get(lineNr);
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        try (Stream<String> st = Files.lines(doc.toPath())

            Optional<String> optionalLine = st.skip(lineNr - 1).findFirst();

            if (optionalLine.isPresent()) {
                dict.put(lineNr, optionalLine.get());
            } else {
                nrLines = nrLines > lineNr ? lineNr : nrLines;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cache.get(lineNr);
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep the file in memory then? You're doing file IO with each incoming request, this is surely going to be slow. Beside `synchronized (this)` is almost certainly unnecessary, what do you need it for?

Comment: @ernest_k What if the file has 3Gb for example, keeping that in memory is harsh... still I would need to iterate over the lines until I got to where I wanted to. The synchronized part I admit I'm not sure as my knowledge is not pro type regarding this, but is so that no other thread can run that part when I need to add to the map

Comment: Did you try using computeIfAbsent and removing the synchronize? Here, you risk blocking every thread working this method, regardless of key. But ConcurrentHashMap uses smarter locking internally (probably CAS, stripe locking etc) which only affect calls with the same key. I don't know about multiple threads reading from the same file however.

Comment: That `synchronized` block is the first thing that's making your requests slow. If `dic` is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, then `dict.put(lineNr, optionalLine.get())` should be safe without `synchronized(this)` (subject to tests, as always). And regarding your file size, I'd say it's really a good idea to use a database (or map implementations that can store data to disk)<br/>Take a look at http://www.mapdb.org/ or guava (as I understand, it also has a disk-backed map implementation)

Comment: @Jeppe I'm not quite sure how I could use the `computeIfAbsent`here. What would I compute?

Comment: @LuisF Whoops, I meant putIfAbsent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V- But it depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: If you have a 3GB file, you should really use some sort of embedded database library. The ability to jump to selected lines in much less than O(n) makes a huge difference. That would also most likely also take care of caching.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing up `ConcurrentMap` with `synchronized(this)` is probably not the right approach. Classes from `java.util.concurrent` package are designed for specific use cases and try to optimize synchronization internally.

Instead I'd suggest to first try a well designed caching library and see if the performance is good enough. One example would be [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). As per [Population](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population) docs it gives you a way to declare how to load the data, even asynchronously:

```
AsyncLoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10_000)
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    // Either: Build with a synchronous computation that is wrapped as asynchronous 
    .buildAsync(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
    // Or: Build with a asynchronous computation that returns a future
    .buildAsync((key, executor) -> createExpensiveGraphAsync(key, executor));
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on [ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), with two assumptions:

1. Multiple threads reading the same file is not a problem.
2. While the documentations says the computation should be simple and short because of blocking, I believe it is only a problem for *same key* (or bucket/stripe) access and only for updates (not reads)? In this scenario, it is not a problem, as we either succesfully compute the value or throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Using this, we achieve only opening the file once per key, by placing that as the computation required to put a key.

```
    public String getLine(int lineNr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (lineNr > nrLines) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(lineNr, (l) -> {
            try (Stream<String> st = Files.lines(path)) {
                Optional<String> optionalLine = st.skip(lineNr - 1).findFirst();
                if (optionalLine.isPresent()) {
                    return optionalLine.get();
                } else {
                    nrLines = nrLines > lineNr ? lineNr : nrLines;
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

I "verified" the second assumption by spawning 3 threads, where:

1. Thread1 computes key 0 by looping infinitely (blocks forever).
2. Thread2 attempts to put at key 0, but never does because Thread1 blocks.
3. Thread3 attempts to put at key 1, and does so immediately.

Try it out, maybe it works or maybe assumptions are wrong and it sucks. The Map uses buckets internally, so the computation may become a bottleneck even with different keys, as it locks the bucket/stripe.